# SAT and TSP Problems

Tags: algorithms, graphs, satisfiability

I am trying to build a tool for solving TSP problem using a conversion to SAT.
Does there exist an efficient conversion from the Travelling Salesman Problem to the Satisfiability problem? Since they both are NP-Complete it seems like the answer might be yes.   I just need a conversion that is tractable in practice.  There are very efficient tools for the satisfiability problem and I think that if I can covert TSP to SAT, I can take advantages of thoses tools.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient conversion"? There exists for sure a logspace reduction, but since TSP is a well-studied problem, TSP-specific algorithms are generally more efficient.

Comment: Ok you are right! "efficient" is somewhat ambigous! here I just need a conversion that is tractable in practice and not a polynomial size conversion!  there are very efficient tool for the satisfiability problem and I think that if I can covert TSP to SAT, I can take advantages of thoses tools.